# How to divide float by integer when both are variables?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, integer

I am writing a program in C. I have two variables one of which is integer and the other one is float. I want to divide the float by the integer and want to get result in float. I am doing the following:

```
int a;
float b=0,c=0;
scanf("%d",&a);
```

I then do some computations on `b` so it has a non-zero value.

```
c = b/(float)a;
printf("c = %d\n", c);
```

The problem is I am getting `c` printed as a rounded number (integer) rather than a float value.

How can I get `c` as a float value?

Comment: [Are you sure this is your real code?](http://ideone.com/kxBIJ0)

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. There should be no rounding. Perhaps you accidentally convert c to int later?

Comment: What values are in the variables?

Comment: Your code would be fine with `c = b / a;`: at least one of the divisors needs to be floating point: `b` already is. The answer must, by coincidence, evaluate to a `float` having no decimal part.

Comment: Please see the edited version of my code.

Comment: The code should work fine just with "c = b / a", because between int and float types, the float type is stronger therefore the conversion should be implicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
printf("c = %d\n", c);
```

`%d` formats c as integer. Use `%f` instead.

Or `std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl` if you prefer.

Comment: printf("c = %f\n", c);

Comment: the error was here:

    printf("c = %2.f\n", c);

I changed this to 

    printf("c = %f\n", c);

thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 55):

*For those here coming from a Google search because of the question's name:*

The result of dividing a float by an integer is a float, this is clean and safe. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float y = 5.0f;
    int x = 4;
    std::cout << y/x << std::endl;
}
```

The output is as expected: `1.25`

Comment: You good samaritan, who acknowledges the "naming" problem .

Answer (score 1):

When printing on a screen try this (this worked for me):

```
printf("c = %f\n", c);
```